# <Response [500]> while POST request

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, quote

Trying to get information with post request but it returns RESPONSE [500]. I have tried to use the get response and it returns response 200 code. I copied the form_data from the website and included in my code.

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from requests.utils import quote

url = 'https://mpcr.cbar.az/service/mpcr.publicSearchApplication'

tax_ids = [
    '1000276532',
    ]

data = {
        'searchFilter': {"fields":"{\"orgTin\":\"%s\"}"},
        'compId': 'frontend',
        'access_token': '123',
        'refresh_token': '123',
        'token': '123',
        'requestNumber': '1p5i9m5s9T9W8',
        '_token': 'MQ2cZyD092qFKknKpZMV0w2ksNhqWj17PSl6iaCG',
        }

with requests.Session() as s:
    for i in tax_ids:
        data["searchFilter"] = quote(json.dumps(data["searchFilter"]["fields"] % i))
        print(data)
        print("--" * 10)
        r = s.post(url, data=data)
        print(r)
```

Comment: Give one example of the correct form data

Comment: `searchFilter: {"fields":"{\"orgTin\":\"1700393071\"}"}
compId: frontend
access_token: 123
refresh_token: 123
token: 123
requestNumber: 155G9M5z9u3z2
_token: PCuZU9NCbyNJkm7VtjpFNF1qeRysPSXkCMXfFbSW`

Comment: @bigbounty the form data contains the tax_id that is searched in itself

Comment: I'm getting `Unregistered customer` for the tax_id given in the question

Comment: yes it is true, this customer is not registered

Comment: is the response worked?

Comment: I tried, not working

Comment: @bigbounty what do you think the problem is?

Comment: I could get 200, but the content is not there

Comment: how? can you share it ?

Comment: I'll write the answer, it can only get you 200, not the content. is that okay?

Comment: yes for now it is okay